# Format text in Linux

Tags: text-formatting

I am trying to format data in a file that needs to be imported to a system. This system does not take more than 65 characters of text in a single line. So, I am trying to format the text in Description column to split as multiple lines as shown in sample below. It would be really helpful for the user if it is a single line Linux command, can you please check if it is possible?

Sample input in file -

```
 
Depth   Description
(ft)    -
12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly, arg, SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m gry, sft, amor, wxy
12400.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m gry, occ rdsh gry, mod firm, amor, wxy, tr CHK
12430.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, wxy
12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, ea, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SST: gry-dk gry, wl consol, v f, ang, p srt, cotd, slily calc cmt, no fluor
```

Depth and Description and the line below it are considered headers.
Depth column contains all numbers, Description column contains text that should be formatted as multiple lines for the system to accept the data.

Desired output with Linux command -

```
 
Depth   Description
(ft)    -
12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, 
        crpxln, prly, arg, SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, 
        amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m gry, sft, 
        amor, wxy
12400.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, 
        arg, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, 
        gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m gry, occ rdsh gry, 
        mod firm, amor, wxy, tr CHK
12430.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, 
        arg, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, 
        gt, mod calc, SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, 
        blky-plty, occ brit, wxy
12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, 
        ea, SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, 
        mod calc, SST: gry-dk gry, wl consol, v f, ang, 
        p srt, cotd, slily calc cmt, no fluor
```

Note - User will not be able to install any Linux package on their machine. (example - par)

Comment: but your line in the output `12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit,` contains 55 chars

Comment: Sorry, updated the question to say 65 characters. Also, I formatted the file just to get an idea but did not count the number of characters on each line.

Comment: You can get *pretty close* to your desired output with just the `fmt` command (from `coreutils`) e.g. `fmt -tw65 file`

Comment: steeldriver - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but it does not work as expected. When I use this command and import the formatted data, all  data is going under Depth instead of placing the text under Description column.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda & RomanPerekhrest. All your solutions work, it gets the format as requested in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -r '3,$s/(.{55} )/\1\n\t/g' file.in
Depth   Description
(ft)    -
12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly,
        arg, SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST:
        lt gry-m gry, sft, amor, wxy
12400.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg,
        SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST:
        lt gry-m gry, occ rdsh gry, mod firm, amor, wxy, tr CHK
12430.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg,
        SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SH:
        blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, wxy
12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, ea,
        SLTST: blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SST:
        gry-dk gry, wl consol, v f, ang, p srt, cotd, slily calc
        cmt, no fluor
```

This leaves spaces at the end of lines that may be stripped b running it through `sed 's/ $//'`.

The expression `3,$s/(.{55} )/\1\n\t/g` will replace any run of 55 characters followed by a space by those same 55 characters (and the space) followed by a newline and an indentation by one tab.  This repeats for all matches of the pattern on the line.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am almost there. The formatted output looks as required with the solution proposed but looks like something is missing. If I edit the file using notepad - Like split the lines <65 characters and import it, it takes it as required with depth on first column and description on second column. But, when I used the script output file and import it, the split lines from description are being imported to the first column instead of second column.

Comment: @NewCoder Does the importer expect the continued lines to be indented by tabs? Does the columns need a tab between them maybe? Is there a tab in the input data?

Comment: That's correct, I think it is looking for lines with tabs. When I edited the file, I used tab instead of spaces and the importer took it as required. Yes, there is a tab between two header columns.

Comment: @NewCoder That's a significant fact to leave out... Hmm... need to think.

Comment: @NewCoder I've fixed this `sed` solution. I will have to redo the `awk` solution too...

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, I now see a tab instead of spaces in the formatted text but when I import the formatted text something is not working right. For example - my imported output looks like this      <pre> 12370.00000 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly, arg,
 SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt
 SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt
12400.00000 
 gry-m gry, sft, amor, wxy
 gry-m gry, sft, amor, wxy
12430.00000 
 
 
12460.00000 
 blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt</pre>

Comment: @NewCoder It's hard to write code against specifications that keeps changing or are unknown. I'd suggest that you figure out exactly what the input data looks like (are all line consisting of a first field, tab, second field, for example), and exactly what the format is that the importer requires (tab-separated fields on _all_ lines? DOS/Unix formatted text input? etc.).

Comment: Sorry for all the back and forth. Yes, all files have a first field(depth) and second field(description), each depth is in a line with a long description. Both Depth and Description are separated by a tab. I used gedit in RHEL to edit the file manually, when I split the line manually I just put a tab at the beginning of split line (new line) which aligned it with the description above. Just checking if there is a way to send/attach the file I have here.

Answer (score 3):

With standard `awk`:

```
{ printf("%s\t", $1) }
{
    linelen = 8;  # assume 8 spaces for the first field

    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        wordlen = length($i);

        if (wordlen + linelen > 65) {
            # break output line since adding next word
            # would make it too long
            printf("\n\t");
            linelen = 8; # count tab as 8 spaces
        }

        if (i < NF) {
            printf("%s ", $i);
            linelen += wordlen + 1; # +1 for the space
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", $i);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.in
Depth   Description
(ft)    -
12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly, arg,
        SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt
        gry-m gry, sft, amor, wxy
12400.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST:
        blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt
        gry-m gry, occ rdsh gry, mod firm, amor, wxy, tr CHK
12430.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST:
        blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SH: blk-dk
        gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, wxy
12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, ea, SLTST:
        blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SST: gry-dk
        gry, wl consol, v f, ang, p srt, cotd, slily calc cmt, no
        fluor
```

The only downside is that this leave trailing spaces on most output lines. You may strip these by passing the output though `sed 's/ $//'`.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR<=2{ print }NR>2{ c=0; r=$1; 
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { 
               if ((length(r) + length($i)) > (!c? 65:61)) { c++; printf "%s\n\t",r; r=$i } 
               else { r=r FS $i } if(i==NF) printf "%s",r } 
            print "" 
     }' file
```

- `NR<=2{ print }` - print the first 2 lines as is
- `r` variable, containing each processed/formatted line

---

The output:

```
Depth   Description
(ft)    -
12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly, arg,
    SLTST: blk, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m
    gry, sft, amor, wxy
12400.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST:
    blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, CLST: lt gry-m
    gry, occ rdsh gry, mod firm, amor, wxy, tr CHK
12430.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, mod firm, crpxln, chky, arg, SLTST:
    blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SH: blk-dk gry,
    mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, wxy
12460.0 SH: blk-dk gry, mod firm, blky-plty, occ brit, ea, SLTST:
    blk-dk gry, firm-mod hd, amor, gt, mod calc, SST: gry-dk gry,
    wl consol, v f, ang, p srt, cotd, slily calc cmt, no fluor
```

Comment: RomanPerekhrest - I get the output as shown above but when I import it - It is considering first column as '12370.0 LS: Mdst, blsh gry, sft, occ mod firm, crpxln, prly, arg,' under Depth which is incorrect since it has to take only 12370.0 and remaining two lines as second column under description. Can you please let me know if anything needs to be changed in the script to make it right?

Comment: @NewCoder, when you say *I import it* - no one see how are doing this. So how can solve your additional issue if I don't see your actual logic?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest - Sorry, I understand. I was just thinking about the formatting part which might be missing a small thing. For some reason, the entire first line is going to the first column but the 2nd and third line are going to the second column. Just wondering if it is possible to send any text after the number (ex - 12370.0) to the next line which may fix the issue? So, in the above case the first line after headers is 12370.0 and the next 3 lines show description.